VSCode Rust debugger Library not loaded
Since I updated my Mac with a M3 Pro to Sonoma 14.4 this spring I'm facing different issues with the "libmysqlclient.20.dylib".
The first issue I faced was that my program wasn't running at all, which I could fix by adding a symlink of the dylib to /usr/local/lib/. Since then I can execute the program and run tests in VSCode.
The original error:
dyld[68426]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.20.dylib
Referenced from: <81873BD6-870A-3D10-A7A2-61F622DDCF25> /Users/hoppmann/Documents/GitHub/EazyFindings2/EazyFindings/target/debug/deps/Logic-4978c930827444e3
Reason: tried: "Several/Pathes/libmysqlclient.20.dylib"

Yesterday I needed to run the debugger of VSCode (CodeLLDB extension) an noticed that the debugger isn't working anymore. When trying to debug I get the following error message:
dyld[65664]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.20.dylib
  Referenced from: <81873BD6-870A-3D10-A7A2-61F622DDCF25> /Users/hoppmann/Documents/GitHub/EazyFindings2/EazyFindings/target/debug/deps/Logic-4978c930827444e3
  Reason: no LC_RPATH's found

After googling for two hours I finally gave up and was debugging with "println".
Today another 2 1/2 hours didn't bring any solution either.
Stuff I've tried:

Deleting and reinstall CodeLLDB

Deleting and reinstall Rust

removing symlink libmysqlclient.20.dylib

replacing symlink by actual copy


Any idea what might go on here, and how to fix this?
